# The corner case of Largest Number At Least Twice of Others

Tags: python

I am taking efforts to solve [Largest Number At Least Twice of Others - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-number-at-least-twice-of-others/)

> 747. Largest Number At Least Twice of Others
>
> In a given integer array `nums`, there is always exactly one largest element.
>
> Find whether the largest element in the array is at least twice as much as every other number in the array.
>
> If it is, return the **index** of the largest element, otherwise return -1.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: nums = [3, 6, 1, 0]
> Output: 1
> Explanation: 6 is the largest integer, and for every other number in the array x,
> 6 is more than twice as big as x.  The index of value 6 is 1, so we return 1.
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
> Output: -1
> Explanation: 4 isn't at least as big as twice the value of 3, so we return -1.
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>
> 1. `nums` will have a length in the range `[1, 50]`.
> 2. Every `nums[i]` will be an integer in the range `[0, 99]`.

The condition `nums` will have a length in the range `[1, 50]`,to don't need to check `len(nums) ==1` and `nums == None`

My solution

```py
class Solution:
    def dominantIndex(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        """
        #solution 1
        #1S#############
        G:List[int], 
        F:index
        RQ: largest and at least twice the second         
        #2S#############
        CP:
        RU: largetst >= second * 2 
        #3S##############
        """
        #base case
        if len(nums) == 1: return -1
        lookup = {nums[i]:i for i in range(len(nums))}
        nums.sort()
        first = nums[-1]
        second = nums[-2]
        if first >= second * 2:
            return lookup[first]
        else:
            return -1 #failure 
        #4C########################
        # nums = [1] output = 0
```

Run the TestCase:

```py
nums = [1]
my output is : -1 #do not exist  such a laregest number 
 #but the expected  is 
0
```

How could understand this Testcase?

My understanding is if there is solely one element, there are no others, others are None, so the condition:

> Find whether the largest element in the array is at least twice as much as every other number in the array.

is not satisfied.

Comment: What if there are multiple largest elements in list? In that case do you want all of their indices?

Comment: As seen in one of the answers, your error seems to be in `if len(nums) == 1: return -1`, should return 0.

Comment: Please note that if there are duplicates in your `nums`, that `lookup` wouldn't be holding every elements. It's better to have always index as the key and with `enumerate` you don't need a `lookup` mapping afterall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your understanding is correct. you can refer to this discussion, they are confused about this, too:
https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-number-at-least-twice-of-others/discuss/176102/Wrong-return-with-1

And I want to say, your solution is not efficient. Your intention is to find the largest two number in `nums`, but `sort` is wasted here, because you only need largest two numbers. so I think heap or two variables are better here:

```
heapq.nlargest(2, nums)
# or find max1, max2 in nums
```

Answer (score 2):

I would completely modify your code and make it more readable. `is_twice` function is guaranteed to return a `True` or `False` depending on if maximum element in the list is atleast twice as greater than every other elements.

```
nums = [1]

def is_twice(lst, max_no):
    return all(max_no >= (2*x) for x in lst if x != max_no)

max_no = max(nums)    
if is_twice(nums, max_no):
    print(nums.index(max_no))  # if you can guarantee there's only one max element else go with below commented code.
    # print([i for i, x in enumerate(nums) if x == max_no])
else:
    print(-1)

# 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is more about a logic issue than a programming issue. The problem asks you to give one result if the largest is greater than "every other number" in the list, but in that test there are no other numbers.

In logic, an "every" statement is considered to be true if the set of items to test is empty. You can see something similar in Python with the `all` function, which usually returns `True` if "every" value in its iterable argument is truthy. If you run `all([])` you get `True`, because there are no falsey values in the empty list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably means that the largest element in the array is assumed to be the at least twice as much as other number in the array **until** it is proven otherwise by one element in the array. Since there are no other element in the array to disprove that, 1 still satisfies the condition and thus the output is its index and not -1.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this, with some changes in first `if` and last `if`:

```
class Solution:
    def dominantIndex(self, nums) -> int:
        """
        #solution 1
        #1S#############
        G:List[int], 
        F:index
        RQ: largest and at least twice the second         
        #2S#############
        CP:
        RU: largetst >= second * 2 
        #3S##############
        """
        #base case
        if len(nums) == 1: return 0
        lookup = {nums[i]:i for i in range(len(nums))}
        nums.sort()
        first = nums[-1]
        second = nums[-2]
        if first >= second * 2:
            return lookup[first]
        else:
            return -1 #failure 
        #4C########################
        # nums = [1] output = 0
```

**Test case:**

```
a = Solution()
print(a.dominantIndex([1, 2, 3, 6]))
```

Output:

```
3
```